# jQuery shift list items on click

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery that has `prev` & `next scrolls`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.playlist-gallery > .prev', function() {
  $('.playlist-item:first').appendTo(".playlist-gallery");
  $('.playlist-item:last').hide().show();
});

$(document).on('click', '.playlist-gallery > .next', function() {
  $(".playlist-item:last").prependTo(".playlist-gallery");
  $(".playlist-item:first").hide().show();
});
```

This is intended to remove the first list item, and send it to the end, or in reverse depending on the button chosen.

What I am seeing is when there are only two items in the list, the above script just keeps making duplicates. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this? I added the buttons outside the gallery div. I have the code set up with 3 items but if you remove one it still works with 2 just fine. Good luck.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.prev', function() {
  $('.playlist-item:first').appendTo(".playlist-gallery");
  $('.playlist-item:last').hide().show();
});

$(document).on('click', '.next', function() {
  $(".playlist-item:last").prependTo(".playlist-gallery");
  $(".playlist-item:first").hide().show();
});
```

```css
.playlist-gallery {
  background: #CCC;
  height: 100px;
}

.playlist-item {
  width: 100px;;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #FFF;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="prev">PREV</button>
<button class="next">NEXT</button>

<div class="playlist-gallery">
  <div class="playlist-item">1</div>
  <div class="playlist-item">2</div>
  <div class="playlist-item">3</div>
</div>
```